# subject inversion after a question word within a clause

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm confused whether to convert the structure of the clause when it starts with a question word within a complex sentence or not. Look at these examples, and tell me which one is FORMALLY accurate:

- I did not know where did she go.

OR

- I did not know where she went.

Comment: "I didn't know where she went" is correct. "Where she went" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), so no inversion is required. The meaning is "I didn't know the answer to the question 'Where did she go?"'.

Answer (score 1):

> **1.** *Where did she go?*  (main clause interrogative)
>
> **2.** *I did not know **[where she went**].* (Subordinate interrogative clause)

When you say "within a clause", you’re referring to the subordinate interrogative clause in ex2. "where did she go", which I’ve bracketed. Such clauses are called interrogative complement clauses (or embedded questions), and they are introduced by one of the interrogative words “who”, “what”, “which”, “where” etc.

With main clause interrogatives like **1.,** the interrogative word usually occupies initial position, and if it is not the subject, it triggers subject-auxiliary inversion (note how auxiliary verb “did” and subject “she” have inverted).

In subordinate interrogative clauses like **2**., on the other hand, the interrogative phrase is initial and normally there is no inversion.

So in your question, you're second example is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

> I didn't know where she went

This is the right one, since this was a negative affirmation, not a negative question. In the first example, you are affirming that you didn't know where she went, therefore, "*did she*" is incorrect. Let's suppose someone told you this: *She went out last night with her friends*, and you repplied: *I didn't know that, where did she go?* In the first clause you are affirming that you didn't know it, and in the second clause you are asking where she went, therefore, you have two clauses; "***I didn't know that***" and ***"where did she go?***" both clauses don't belong to the same statement, because one is affirmation and the other is a question, but in your sentence, both clauses belong to the same statement, because you are affirming that you didn't know where she went, this is an affirmation, both clauses are affirmative.

Here are others examples of different clauses and clauses that belong to the same statement:

> I didn't know where he traveled to
>
> I didn't know, where did he travel to?
>
> I don't know where she will spend her vacations.
>
> I don't know, where will she spend her vacations?

In the examples above you can realize that I affirmed something, and in the others you see that I affirm something, and ask for other directly referred to the same clause, and bear in mind that *comma* will always be placed after the *negative clause*, as you can see, in order to separate one clause from the other, and to indicate to the reader that a new clause is coming.

Comment: In "I didn't know where she went", the element "where she went" is an interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement to the verb "know". Same construction applies to your other examples.

Comment: Yeah, they belong to the same clause, "I didn't know where he traveled to" it belongs to the same clause because he is affirming it, but in the others examples, I should have increased an "it" after know, it would shut the first clause, and the new one would come, which is the question: "where did she travel to?"

Comment: "I didn't know where she went" isn't an interrogative clause, he was affirming that he didn't know where SHE went (IT), if he was going to ask where she went, that's how it is supposed to be: "I didn't know it, where did she go?"

Comment: I didn't say it was. I said that the element "where she went" is an interrogative (embedded question).

Comment: Are you sure about what you are saying?, I presume you meant to say it is a negative clause, right? The only way to turn this clause into an interrogative clause would be this: I didn't know it, where DID she travel to?

Comment: No, it's an interrogative clause (embedded question). The meaning is "I didn't know the answer to the question 'Where did she go?"' It's a very common construction in English.

Comment: A very common construction? What construction is this that I have never seen so far? As far as I know, interrogative sentences are those proceeded by the "?" and it also implies in the construction of the sentence: He went there: Did he go there?
I was there, Was I there?
I don't know where he went
I don't know, where did he go?

but if you are still sure about it, I'd like to send you some examples of negative and interrogative constructions: 
http://www.k12reader.com/interrogative-sentences/

http://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-sentences/

Comment: It's a **subordinate interrogative**, not a direct question. The main clause (direct) equivalent would be "Where did she go? Example abound, compare "I know _where is_", "I'm unsure _whether he accepted the offer_". Look up "embedded question" in your grammar book or on the 'Net.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this isn't what the OP's question meant, he wants to know whether those two sentences are right, he is referring to a negative question, not an interrogative, that's why: **I didn't know where she went** is the correct one, because it's not an interrogative clause, but a negative one, and he implies to say that he didn't know IT - **IT**: Where she went

Comment: It was precisely what the OP meant. The OP was asking about subject inversion after a question word, and which of their 2 examples was correct. In the two examples given, the question word "where" introduces a subordinate interrogative clause, but subordinate interrogative clauses do **not** (normally) exhibit inversion. Thus only the OP's second example without inversion is correct. See the full answer I have now posted